# Specify target elevation with r.viewshed in QGIS processing toolbox?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, viewshed

How do I specify the target-height in r.viewshed when using the operator through QGIS's processing toolbox? It doesn't seem to be available.

Who should I contact to adjust the interface such that the target-height option could be added to the r.viewshed dialogue box? Is that something that I can do myself?

In the mean-time, is the viewshed analysis plugin the only other option? It seems to routinely give me memory errors and crash, so I'd prefer to stay away from it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to edit C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\grass7\description\r.viewshed.txt

```
r.viewshed
Computes the viewshed of a point on an elevation raster map.
Raster (r.*)
ParameterRaster|input|Elevation|False
ParameterString|coordinates|Coordinate identifying the viewing position|0,0
ParameterString|observer_elevation|Viewing position height above the ground|1.75
ParameterString|max_distance|Maximum distance from the viewing point (meters)|10000
ParameterBoolean|-c|Consider earth curvature (current ellipsoid)|False
OutputRaster|output|Intervisibility
```

to include

```
ParameterString|target_elevation|Offset for target elevation above the ground|0.0
```

Create feature requests on http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues to suggest Processing tool changes.

Comment: I have submitted the change as https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/2875 to the code repository

Comment: The change has been merged. It will go into the next QGIS release, I suppose.